# asp.net mvc 6 dynamic db connection for asp.net identity

Tags: asp.net-identity, asp.net-core-mvc

I have

**Controller and IActionResult as below**

```
 public HomeController(
            UserManager<CustomerApplicationUser> userManager,
            SignInManager<CustomerApplicationUser> signInManager,
            IMemoryCache cache)
        {
            _userManager = userManager;
            _signInManager = signInManager;
            _cache = cache;
        }

[HttpPost]
[AllowAnonymous]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<IActionResult> Login(LoginViewModel model, string returnUrl = null)
{

ViewData["ReturnUrl"] = returnUrl;
var companyResult = new Company();

using (var GeneralCompanyContext = new GeneralCompanyContext())
{
companyResult = await GeneralCompanyContext.Company.FirstOrDefaultAsync(t => t.CompanyNumber == model.CompanyNumber);
}

using (var context = new CustomerContext(companyResult.ConnectionString))
{

var LoginResult = await _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.Email, model.Password, false, lockoutOnFailure: false);

}     
}
```

**Startup.cs**

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{

services.AddEntityFramework().AddSqlServer()
                    .AddDbContext<CustomerContext>()
                    .AddDbContext<GeneralCompanyContext>();

services.AddIdentity<CustomerApplicationUser, IdentityRole>().AddEntityFrameworkStores<CustomerContext>().AddDefaultTokenProviders();
services.AddIdentity<GeneralCompanyApplicationUser, IdentityRole>().AddEntityFrameworkStores<GeneralCompanyContext>().AddDefaultTokenProviders();
```

}

**CustomerContext class**:

```
CustomerContext : : IdentityDbContext<CustomerApplicationUser>
{
 private readonly string _ConnectionString;

     public CustomerContext()
     {
     _ConnectionString = Configuration["Data:DefaultConnection:MigrationConnectionString"]).ToString();
     }

     public CustomerContext(string ConnectionString)
     {
     _ConnectionString = ConnectionString;
     }

   protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(_ConnectionString);
        base.OnConfiguring(optionsBuilder);
    }
}
```

**Question:**

I have 2 dbcontext as CustomerContext and GeneralCompanyContext.

**CustomerContext** has database for customer.

**GeneralCompanyContext** has all database connection strings for all customers.

When project started

services.AddEntityFramework().AddSqlServer() adds connection string from

**Configuration["Data:DefaultConnection:MigrationConnectionString"]**

automaticly.So when i try to login on Index Iactionresult , signinmanager connection string always display Configuration["Data:DefaultConnection:MigrationConnectionString"] connection string.

How can i set connection string for u**sermanager (asp.net identity)** from **companyResult.ConnectionString** ?

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The thing is that the way you are trying to do it, most probably it won't work. You have to know the company number in advance, before even entering the login method at all,e.g. pass it as query param or use sub domain to decide or another approach.
I had to do something similar recently in ASP.NET Core 1.0. Cannot post you exact code as I ended up adding an infrastructural code around all this, but I'll try to give you some guidance.

The first thing to know is that you can replace the `CustomerContext` connection string in the `OnConfiguring` method of the context. That is the last resort.

[Source](https://ef.readthedocs.org/en/latest/miscellaneous/configuring-dbcontext.html#onconfiguring).

```
public class CustomerDbContext : DbContext
{
    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        // optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer("Your connection string should injected here.");
    }
}
```

The next step is to know where and when to get the connection string from the **GeneralCompanyDatabase**. This should happen in the equivalent of the BeginRequest in MVC 5 place - in a middleware.

```
public class Tenant
{
    public string CustomerConnectionString { get; set; }
}

public class TenantMiddleware
{
    private readonly RequestDelegate next_;

    public TenantMiddleware(RequestDelegate next)
    {
        next_ = next;
    }

    public async Task Invoke(HttpContext httpContext, GeneralCompanyContext companyContext)
    {
        // You have to know your company number here somehow !!
        string customerConnectionString = await companyContext.Company.FirstOrDefaultAsync(t => t.CompanyNumber == 1).ConnectionString;
        Tenant tenant = new Tenant{ CustomerConnectionString = customerConnectionString };

        httpContext.Items["customerTenant"] = tenant;

        await next_(httpContext);
    }
}
```

Now as you have the connection string, you have to make the `Tenant` object injectable in the CustomerDbContext

In `Startup.cs`

```
services.AddScoped(prov => 
prov.GetService<IHttpContextAccessor>()?.HttpContext?.GetTenant());
```

`GetTenant()` is an extension method of the HttpContext.

```
public static Tenant GetTenant(this HttpContext context)
{
    object myObj;
    if (context.Items.TryGetValue("customerTenant", out myObj))
    {
        return myObj as Tenant;
    }

    return null;
}
```

Now your CustomerDbContext should look like something like:

```
public class CustomerDbContext : DbContext
{
    private Tenant tenant_;

    public CustomerDbContext(Tenant tenant)
    {
        tenant_ = tenant;       
    }
    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(tenant.CustomerConnectionString);
    }
}
```

And at this point the `SignInManager` will use the correct connection string. 
But the way you have started, I highly doubt you will make it working. Because where you try to replace the connection string everything is already instantiated and configured.
Again I just typed the code snippets by hand to illustrate the idea. 
Additionally, consider using the `IMemoryCache` in the middleware to cache the connection string and avoid doing db calls on each request.